# Exporting or saving .rtf from Excel

Tags: excel, rtf

I want to export a table from Excel 2013 to .rtf (rich text format) so I can link to the .rtf from Sketchup Layout (version 8 pro) - the only format that Sketchup allows for this. The table is typically like this, (and I get these as .csv files) but could run to several hundred records:

```
Name       Unit   Description
Buxus sem   10     some text
```

Does anyone know of a macro or other method to do this straight from Excel?

Comment: Export to Word and save as rtf.

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to cut out as many steps as possible from this process: I'm looking for a way to save, or export directly from Excel, so far I get my .csv file and link to it via Excel's Data Import - that way I can only update the .csv, if I can then export to .rtf from Excel it would be simple for me (I hopiing to use Excel as a bridge).